# How to fix 'conda env switching' problem while changing directory?

Tags: python, virtualenv, conda

I want to use my own virtualenv which is created by conda in Ubuntu 14.04.
But the problem is that the virtualenv is switched to base while changing the directory using cd command.

```
conda activate py2  # using own virtualenv 'py2'
cd ..
# Then, the virtualenv will be deactivated and eventually switched to base env.
```

How can I use my own virtualenv continuously before I explicitly type
`conda deactivate`?

Comment: I think you need to provide more evidence, like show us `conda info` before and after `cd`. Otherwise, I've never seen anything like this before. An env being activated corresponds to editing `PATH`, so unless your `cd` is aliased to change `PATH`, this seems impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Oh I find the answer and it was just zsh(bash) issue.

Actually, I am using zsh which is forked from this git repository.
(https://github.com/wookayin/dotfiles)

This package included some auto-switch functions while changing directory for users' convenience.

In conclusion, it was not the problem but just an additional function.